# Very Slow Sharepoint (Authentication Problem? - Getting 401 errors on images and styles)

Tags: performance, sharepoint, ntlm, http-status-code-401

I'm currently using Team Foundation Server and WSS 3.0 as the Team Portal. After the installation and configuring, I noticed the application was very slow sometimes, taking minutes to load a page. Then I googled it and found n solutions, none solved my problem.

Using Firebug I noticed I was getting a lot of 401 errors, mostly in _layouts and _themes folders.

Error image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmurI.jpg

Authentication method is NTLM

Any clue on what's happening? The page loads, it just takes forever before showing up.

**EDIT: Here's fiddler statistics:**

Request Count:  161
Bytes Sent:     144.851 (headers:133249; body:11602)
Bytes Received: 400.222 (headers:69769; body:330453)

**ACTUAL PERFORMANCE**

Requests started at:    09:47:55.449
Responses completed at: 09:50:03.311
Aggregate Session time: 00:03:11.542
Sequence (clock) time:  00:02:07.8627850
TCP/IP Connect time:    239ms

**RESPONSE CODES**

HTTP/401:   84
HTTP/200:   74
HTTP/302:   2
HTTP/404:   1

**RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)**

application/x-javascript:   218.048
               ~headers~:   69.769
               text/html:   37.837
               image/gif:   31.467
                text/css:   27.506
               image/png:   10.133
              image/jpeg:   3.937
         text/javascript:   1.007
                text/xml:   518

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have had exactly this problem with a sharepoint site.

The root cause is the way that NTLM works. The NTLM handshake is a 401.2 401.1 followed by a 200. Allways 3 requests for each file.

For each request, the web server will send a request to the AD server. The problem is that by default there is only 2 connections to the AD server. So the request get backed up and retried.

There are two things that you can do:

- Make sure that you are caching the gif files (then you will not have to get them all the time)
- Switch to Kerberos

**Edit**

For setting up Kerberos have a look at this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2007/04/23/configuring-kerberos-for-sharepoint-2007-part-1-base-configuration-for-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm trying to switch to Kerberos but I don't know how it's supposed to work. The sharepoint site is hosted in a server but the databases are stored in another. I'm guessing I need to set the SPN in the host server and specify the service account, but i'm getting "RPC Server Unavailable".

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [this common SharePoint performance fix](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/04/new-approach-to-solve-sharepoints.html)?

Comment: Yes, at first I thought the certificate revocation list was the problem. But noticed no changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify this happens on all clients?  If you access the page from a browser on the server itself, do you still get this result?

If you haven't yet, turn off IPv6 in your network settings.  Also, verify your DNS settings.  Slow AD authentication + RPC Server Unavailable leads me to believe you may have addressing issues.  Does everything seem responsive from a ping?  When you log on to your machine, does it take a long time to log in (another symptom of DNS setting problems)?

Comment: I think it can't be a network issue, because when I access the page from a browser on the server itself, I get the same slowdown problems. Could the RPC Server Unavailable problem be caused by closed ports which are required for kerberos ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are 401 errors on CSS / js / Images / .axd. with sharepoint /
 NTLM authentification
You must configure the anonymous access on the webapplication and if you have a publishing portal activate the anonymous on : 
 - style library
 - sitecollectionimage

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem with css files I downloaded. For some reason, the windows setting "encrypt contents to secure data" was checked for some files. After removing this setting, everything went fine. Be sure to unblock them if necessary.

(just to be sure: I'm talking about (file)->properties->advanced->encrypt data...)